# How can i rewrite the title of the header of my xamarin forms app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following "error": when i click a item of my menu in my app, i need to have a custom title at the header of the page, but the app show me only the text from my viewmodel thats build the items of menu:

```
   MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<HomeMasterMenuItem>(new[]
                {
                    new HomeMasterMenuItem { Id = 0, Label = "Buscar Redes",  TargetType = typeof(FiltersNets)  },
                    new HomeMasterMenuItem { Id = 1, Label = "Inventario", TargetType = typeof(Inventory), Image = "ic_home_orange_100_18dp.png"  },
                    new HomeMasterMenuItem { Id = 2, Label = "Recepciones", Title = "recep", TargetType = typeof(Receptions), Image = "receptions.png"  },
                    new HomeMasterMenuItem { Id = 3, Label = "Despachos", TargetType = typeof(ShipOuts) },
                    new HomeMasterMenuItem { Id = 6, Label = "Salir", TargetType = typeof(MainPage) },
                });
```

i used a binding to write my custom test (storaged in a property) into the title of xaml byt had no results :(  the text was assigned but the header kept the text from homemastermenuitem

have any idea? bye.

Comment: if you mean the Title displayed in the NavigationBar, that is generally set by the Title property of the currently displayed page

Comment: I think you have a data binding with the HomeMasterMenuItem, you need to remove it.